# Remove a program from "how do you want to open this file" list on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

I wanted to open a file with another program so I did open with > choose another app > more apps and a list of apps show up.

This is a screenshot of the list and I want to remove the "idle" files because it's useless.

[image: Screen Shot]

How do I do this?

Comment: Remove the `idle` entry contained in the appropriate registry key.  You could also just restore the default list.

Comment: @Ramhound how do i restore the default list?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18119/remove-programs-from-open-with-menu-in-explorer/

Comment: Without the key myself, and without knowing the file extension, that's the best I can do

Answer (score 2):

I used this program [OpenWithView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/openwithview.zip).

Found this solution [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/remove-apps-from-windows-open-with-list/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You may have uninstalled the programs incorrectly and left these empty entries when windows searches for them. In the future use the Windows "Add/remove programs" feature in the control panel.

In the meantime you could redownload those programs and install them, then uninstall them to remove them properly from your menu. Do not go into the Program files folder and delete folders of programs you no longer use. That only works for Macs.